# Allocating specific logical cores to specific processes exclusively, Windows, C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

If possible I do wish to allocate a logical core to a single process exclusively.

I am aware that Winbase.h contains Get/SetProcessAffinityMask and SetThreadAffinityMask.

I can get all processes running when the specific process is started and set their affinities to other logical cores, however, I do not want to check all processes in a periodic manner, for instance in order to deal with processes launched after the initiation of my process.

Furthermore there will be other processes which need to use specific logical cores only exclusively (no other process shall waste resources on that logical core). For instance my process shall run on core 15 but another shall run only on core 14.

Is there a better and more permanent way to allocate specific logical cores to specific processes than above mentioned Get/SetProcessAffinityMask scheme.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/40453645/103167

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, why I do need this is less about timing and computer science and more about contracts and customer demands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows is not a real-time operating system. Windows is designed to do preemptive multitasking with isolated processes, like basically any other modern desktop OS. A process is not supposed to just lock out every other process from a particular core, therefore, there is no API to explicitly do so (at least I'm not aware of one). It's up to the OS scheduler to decide which threads get to run when and where. That's the whole idea. You can use [thread priorities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/scheduling-priorities) to tell the scheduler that certain threads should be given a chance to run over others. You can use [affinity masks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/multiple-processors) to tell the scheduler which cores a thread can be scheduled to. You can even [set a preferred core for your thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadidealprocessor). But you don't get to schedule threads yourself.

Note that there's apparently a way to get something a bit like what you're looking for to work on Linux (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583146/whole-one-core-dedicated-to-single-process) for more). I don't think similar possibilities exist on Windows. Yes you could try to hack together some solution based on a background task that continuously monitors and adjusts the priorities and affinity masks of all the threads in the system to approximate the desired behavior (like the person in [the question linked by Ben Voigt above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453645/set-process-affinity-of-system-process-to-reserve-core-for-own-application) has apparently tried, and failed to achieve). But why would you want to do that? It goes completely against the very nature of everything an OS like Windows is designed to do. To me, what you are asking sounds a lot like what you're really looking for is a completely different kind of operating system, or maybe even no operating system at all. Boot the CPU straight into your own image and you get to drive all the cores in whatever way you fancy…